# Creating matching brackets- awk :sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a data set that has three patterns:

First:

```
abrasion abrade:stem<>ion:suffix
abstainer abstain:stem<>er:suffix
abstention abstain:stem<>ion:suffix
```

Second:

```
inaccurate in:prefix<>accurate:stem
inactive in:prefix<>active:stem
```

Third:

```
incommunicable in:prefix<>communicate:stem<>able:suffix
incompatibility in:prefix<>compatible:stem<>ity:suffix
```

I need to convert the above to following form : Matching the brackets in the way for Penn Tree Bank  (http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/PennTreebank1995.pdf)

First:

```
abrasion ((abrade:stem) ion:suffix)
abstainer ((abstain:stem)er:suffix)
abstention ((abstain:stem)ion:suffix)
```

Second:

```
inaccurate (in:prefix(accurate:stem))
inactive (in:prefix(active:stem))
```

Third:

```
incommunicable (in:prefix ((communicate:stem)able:suffix))
incompatibility (in:prefix ((compatible:stem)ity:suffix))
```

The code, I am working is using  awk

```
{
    n = gsub(/<>/,")",$2)
    s = sprintf("%*s",n,"")
    gsub(/ /,"(",s)
    print "(" $1, s "((" $2 "))"
}
```

**EDIT**

More complex forms

```
nationalistic national: stem <>ism:suffix<>ist:suffix<>ic:suffix
```

to:

```
nationalistic ((((national: stem) ism:suffix)ist:suffix)ic:suffix)
```

It is not producing the expected outputs that mentioned in the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be general enough as it takes into account `:stem`, `:prefix`, and `:suffix` for matching:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\n"}{
  a=gensub(/([a-zA-Z]*):stem/,"(\\1:stem)", "g");
  b=gensub(/(\([a-zA-Z]*:stem\))<>([a-zA-Z]*):suffix/,"(\\1\\2:suffix)", "g", a);
  c=gensub(/([a-zA-Z]*:prefix)<>(.*)/,"(\\1\\2)", "g", b);
  print c;}' testfile
```

Demo here: https://ideone.com/U3ux91

**EDIT**

This should take care of multiple suffixes and prefixes:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\n"}{
   a=gensub(/([a-zA-Z]*):stem/,"(\\1:stem)", "g");
   while ( a ~ /stem)<>.*:suffix/) {
     a=gensub(/(\([a-zA-Z]*:stem\).*?)<>([a-zA-Z]*):suffix/,"(\\1\\2:suffix)", "g", a);
   }
   while ( a ~ /<>/) {
     a=gensub(/([a-zA-Z]*?:prefix)<>(.*)/,"(\\1\\2)", "g", a);
   }
   print a;}' test
```

Demo here: https://ideone.com/U7LYXi
(sorry if antinationalistic is not a word, but for testing sake....)

Comment: Yes. This should be general

Comment: @Guido  What will happen  if one word has 3 prefix and  3 suffix

Comment: @Karun well that was not part of the question; anyway, is it possible for a word to have more than one prefix or suffix at the same time? (sorry if yes, english is not my native language). Wouldn't that word be on different lines in your input, as the same stem with different suffixes?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Yes. I can give some examples. Please check the newly added

Comment: Yeah. This works fine. antinationalist  is a word  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antinationalist

Comment: @Karun Please check the script

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ  This is very slow for  100 Tokens

Comment: @Karun that's because regexes are not the best tool to obtain your desired results, but again, that's what was asked in your question.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ. Is possible to increase the speed some how?

Comment: @Karun I don't see a way for a single regex to achieve the transofrmation you are looking for, so having three regexes for each line will have to be kinda slower than writing a proper parser, as Karafka answer tries to do for instance

Answer (score 1):

The expected output for pattern 1 may have problem, the brackets are not paired, I **guess** it was typos and it should be:

```
abrasion ((abrade:stem)ion:suffix)
abstainer ((abstain:stem)er:suffix)
abstention ((abstain:stem)ion:suffix)
```

I make this awk script:

```
awk -v d="<>" '{$2="("$2")"}
$1~/^ab/{sub(d,")",$2);$2="(" $2}
$1~/^ina/{sub(d,"(",$2);$2=$2")"}
$1~/^inc/{sub(d,"((",$2);sub(d,")",$2);$2=$2")"}7' file
```

with your 3 patterns example in same file, it gives:

```
abrasion ((abrade:stem)ion:suffix)
abstainer ((abstain:stem)er:suffix)
abstention ((abstain:stem)ion:suffix)
inaccurate (in:prefix(accurate:stem))
inactive (in:prefix(active:stem))
incommunicable (in:prefix((communicate:stem)able:suffix))
incompatibility (in:prefix((compatible:stem)ity:suffix))
```

Comment: unhappiness (un:prefix<>hap:stem<>y:suffix<>ness:suffix). This code is not producing desired output. It checks only word that has prefix ^ab  inc etc. I need a egneral one

Comment: @Karun it is not a "general" solution, it works just for your examples in question. I didn't read the  PDF paper, and I will not do it. You should explain the requirement in question, not just attached/linked a 318 pages paper.

Comment: @Kent I am sorry. My intention was to give an overview of the topic

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'<>| ' -v OFS= '{ 
    $1 = $1 " " 
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { 
        if ($i ~ /prefix$/)    { $i = "(" $i; $NF = $NF ")" } 
        if ($i ~ /stem\)?$/)   { stem = i; $i = "(" $i ")" } 
        if ($i ~ /suffix\)?$/) { $i = $i ")"; $stem = "(" $stem } } 
    } { print }'
```

Comment: could you add an explanation or justification?

Comment: @C_B Well OP said that the accepted answer was slow for large datasets. This version doesn't suffer from that problem.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'function wrap(v) {return "("v")"; }
      {n=split($2,a,"<>"); 
       if(n==3) w=wrap(a[1] wrap(wrap(a[2]) a[3])); 
       else if(a[1]~/:prefix/) w=wrap(a[1] wrap(a[2])); 
       else w=wrap(wrap(a[1]) a[2]);
       print $1, w}' stems

abrasion ((abrade:stem)ion:suffix)
abstainer ((abstain:stem)er:suffix)
abstention ((abstain:stem)ion:suffix)
inaccurate (in:prefix(accurate:stem))
inactive (in:prefix(active:stem))
incommunicable (in:prefix((communicate:stem)able:suffix))
incompatibility (in:prefix((compatible:stem)ity:suffix))
```